# Swift UiTableView with UISegmentedControl not refreshing rows

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView.
At the top I have a UISegmentedController and then a UITableView.
I want the rows to be sorted when you press the segmented controls. Everything is working fine, the rows get displayed properly, but when I press the segmented control button, I call a method that sorts the array that has been displayed in the table view, but they don't get refreshed in the view unless I don't scroll to the bottom and to the top. I call the method tableView.reloadData() after sorting this array, but it doesn't update the tableview.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import EventKit


extension RangeReplaceableCollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable {

  mutating func removeObject(object : Generator.Element) {
    if let index = self.indexOf(object) {
        self.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
  }
}

class EventsViewController: UIViewController {

var calendarName:String!
var currentStat = Stat()
var eventStore = EKEventStore() //represents the Calendar database. Point of contact for accessing calendar
var icloudEventSource: EKSource?  //represents the account that a calendar belongs to.
var startDate=NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-31556926)
var endDate=NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(31556926)
var yourCalendar: EKCalendar?
var calendar: EKCalendar? //represents a calendar in Event Kit
var numberOfCalendars : Int = 0
var calendarsArray = NSMutableArray()
var calendarsPrueba : [EKCalendar]?
var calendarioSeleccionado:String!
var delegate: passDataBackDelegate?
var events : [EKEvent]!
var tableView : UITableView?
var selectedMarks = [StatEvents]()
var selectedIndex = [NSIndexPath]()
var orderedStatEvents = [StatEvents]()


@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            orderTable(0)

        case 1:
            orderTable(1)
        default:
            break; 
    }
}


func orderTable(order: Int) {
    switch order {

        case 0:
            currentStat.statEvents.sortInPlace({ $0.name.compare($1.name) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })

        case 1:
            currentStat.statEvents.sortInPlace({ $0.name.compare($1.name) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending })
        default:
            break;
    }

    tableView?.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event,
        completion: {(granted: Bool, error:NSError?) in
            if !granted {
                print("Access to store not granted")
            }
    })


    // Buscamos la cuenta de iCloud que contiene los calendarios
    for source in eventStore.sources{
        if source.sourceType.rawValue == EKSourceType.CalDAV.rawValue && source.title.lowercaseString == "icloud"{
            icloudEventSource = source

        }
    }


    ///////Mostramos solo calendarios de iCloud//////
    if (icloudEventSource != nil){
        let calendars = icloudEventSource!.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event)

        print("1 The iCloud event source was found = \(icloudEventSource!.title)")
        print("1 Number of calendars = \(calendars.count)")

        for calendars in calendars{
            yourCalendar = (calendars as EKCalendar)
            print(yourCalendar!.title)
            calendarsArray.addObject(yourCalendar!.title)

        }
    }else{
        print("Could not find the iCloud event source")
    }



    //////Mostramos todos los calendarios///////
    let calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event) //Devuelve los calendarios que son eventos

    numberOfCalendars = calendars.count
    print("Number of calendars = \(calendars.count)")

    for calendars in calendars as [EKCalendar] {
        print("events = \(calendars.title)")
        calendarsArray.addObject(calendars.title)
    }


    func calendarEventsWithName( name:String ) -> [EKCalendar]? {
        let calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event) as [EKCalendar]
        for cal in calendars {
            if cal.title == name {
                return [cal]
            }
        }
        print ("failed to find calendar")
        return nil
    }


    let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: calendarEventsWithName(currentStat.statCalendar))


    print("startDate:\(startDate) endDate:\(endDate)")
    events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate) as [EKEvent]!

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" //format style. Browse online to get a format that fits your needs.


    if events != nil {
        print(events.count)
        for i in events {
            let components = calendar.components(.Hour, fromDate: i.startDate, toDate: i.endDate, options: [])

            currentStat.statEvents.append(StatEvents(name: i.title, dateRanges: [i.startDate, i.endDate], hours: components.hour))
        }
    } else {
        print("No hay eventos en este calendario")
    }
}




// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return events.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(8.0)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row].name)  \(currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row].dateRanges) horas=\(currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row].hours)"

    if let selectedPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        let selected = selectedPaths.filter(){ $0 == indexPath }
        if selected.count > 0 {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }

    return cell
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if (selectedMarks.contains(currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row])){

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
        print("borro")           
        selectedMarks.removeObject(currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row])

    } else {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }
        print("añado")
        selectedMarks.append(currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row]) //add the object to selectedMarks
    }
    selectedIndex = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!
    tableView.reloadData()

}


@IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {

    selectedMarks.sortInPlace({ $0.dateRanges[0].compare($1.dateRanges[0]) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })
    currentStat.statEvents = selectedMarks
    navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that tableView is not nil when you call orderTable method?

Comment: @NikitaLeonov you are right! The tableView is nil at this moment. How can this be possible??

Comment: I posted this as an answer, now lets debug your code within an answer and find a root cause.

Comment: I updated my answer :) I do not see anywhere in the code tableView initialized with UITableView instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way how I can imagine it is happening — tableView is nil in a orderTable call.

I can not find anywhere in the code assignment of table to a tableView. How is it initialized? It also worth to mention that tableView in delegate and dataSource methods a local parameter of methods, not an instance variable.

Mark it as IBOutlet and set it in IB as you do with textLabel and segmentedControl or you can change UIViewController to UITableViewController and update IB as well.

Comment: Omg, I didn't realize it wasn't an IBOutlet! I lost about the whole day only for this silly thing!! Thanks again!

Comment: @Ruben np, Usually the most time consuming bugs are obvious one.